# IE11 'Blob is undefined' error

Tags: javascript, blob, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to download a file from the browser.

In JS I try to create a Blob from the data I get returned from the server but in IE11 the Blob is undefined and therefore cannot be created.

> JS fails in this line with error : 'Blob' is undefined

Works correctly in Chrome and Firefox.

```
var blob = new Blob([data], {'type':"application/csv"});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Blob constructor has been available in IE since IE10 - perhaps you're in some "compatibility mode" in IE that causes this to fail - check the Emulation tab in the Developer Tools to check the Document Mode

Comment: you were right! It was the compatibility mode. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The Blob object is available from IE10 (included), see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob

So it should be working, anyhow if you need to support lower versions,
there's a polyfill - https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js/

Edit: make sure you're not running IE11 emulating an older version (F12).

Comment: From my tests, it does - I have used it in a project of mine.